# how to skip Kafka and zookeeper logs in debug mode

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-zookeeper

Using spring boot `application.yml` and `logback.xml` property files.

I tried with below `application.yml` properties but its not working.

```
spring.logging.level.org.apache.kafka:
 clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig: INFO
 clients.producer.ProducerConfig: INFO
 common.utils.AppInfoParser: INFO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting this in config file

```
<logger name="org.apache.zookeeper" level="OFF"/>
```

Similarly for kafka.